# Change style of GeoJSON circle marker by feature properties

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have GeoJSON Feature Collection of points with a text property 'Proyecto' and I want to change the color of the circle marker for each point to vary by that property.

I've created a function to get the color based on the five unique values for the 'Proyecto' property:

```
function getColor(d) {
  return d = 'Vivienda saludable' ? '#a6cee3' :
         d = 'Programa OPAS- 1969, Prevención de conflictos, desarrollo de acuerdos y construcción de la paz en comunidades con personas internamente desplazadas en Chiapas, México'  ? '#1f78b4' :
         d = 'Familias fuertes, amor y límites'  ? '#b2df8a' :
         d = 'e-Health, acceso a servicios médicos de telemedicina en comunidades indígenas en extrema pobreza'  ? '#33a02c' :
         d = 'Casas maternas'   ? '#fb9a99' :
             '#FFEDA0';
         }
```

I then create the GeoJSON layer, call pointToLayer, create a circle marker and call the getColor function, and create a popup from the properties of the GeoJSON file.

```
var puntos = L.geoJson(puntos_chiapas, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 10, fillOpacity: 0.85, color: getColor(feature.properties.Proyecto)});
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(
                "<b>Proyecto: </b>" +
                feature.properties.Proyecto + 
                "</br>" + 
                "<b>Ubicación: </b>" +
                feature.properties.Ubicación +
                "</br>" +  
                "<b>Sector: </b>" +
                feature.properties.Sector +
                "</br>" + 
                "<b>Esquema: </b>" +
                feature.properties.Esquema
            )
            }

    });
```

The resulting map and points all show only the color of the first 'Proyecto' text from the getColor function. What am I doing wrong?

I've included [the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/queclay/jgwft59q/1/). You may need to toggle off the polygon layer to see the points.

Comment: The comparison operator should be `==` like in `d == 'Vivienda saludable' ? ...`

Answer (score 6):

The problem lay in the `getColor` function.  You need to use == as the comparison operator and not the assignment operator (single =).  With respect, stacking ternary operators like that does not make for readable code. Simply rewriting the function with a `switch` statement solves your problem:

```
function getColor(d) {
  switch (d) {
    case 'Vivienda saludable':
      return '#a6cee3';
    case 'Programa OPAS- 1969, Prevención de conflictos, desarrollo de acuerdos y construcción de la paz en comunidades con personas internamente desplazadas en Chiapas, México':
      return '#1f78b4';
    case 'Familias fuertes, amor y límites':
      return '#b2df8a';
    case 'e-Health, acceso a servicios médicos de telemedicina en comunidades indígenas en extrema pobreza':
      return '#33a02c';
    case 'Casas maternas':
      return '#fb9a99';
    default:
      return '#FFEDA0';
  }
}
```

See revised [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y4vrxrw/3/) (I swapped the order of your layers merely for my convenience - but it's the switch statement you're interested in anyway).